# Zend 1 - SQL FROM expression alias

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm performing a sub-select in the `FROM` clause of a query. The sub-select is being passed to the query as a `Zend_Db_Expr` as it's supposed to be, however I can't seem to alias the sub-select.

Example:

```
$a = $adapter->select()->order('abc.id DESC');
$b = $adapter->select()->from('b');

$a->from(new Zend_Db_Expr("($b) AS xxx", 'xxx.id'); // does not work - always aliases as "t"
```

The reason why the alias is always 't' comes from the following line:
https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Select.php#L787

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your own aliases like that:

```
$a = $adapter->select()->order('abc.id DESC');
$b = $adapter->select()->from('b');

$a->from(array('xxx'=>$b), 'id');
```

Which results in: `` SELECT `xxx`.`id` FROM (SELECT `b`.* FROM `b`) AS `xxx` ORDER BY `abc`.`id` DESC ``